# Got malformed error when do replace string manipulation

Tags: replace, splunk

I was following string [manipulation docs](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/DSP/1.1.0/FunctionReference/Stringmanipulation) from splunk itself

> 1. SPL2 example Returns the "body" field with phone numbers redacted.
>
> `...| eval body=replace(cast(body, "string"), /[0-9]{3}[-.][0-9]{3}[-.][0-9]{4}/, "<redacted>");`

But when I tried to do query

```
... | eval hostname=replace(cast(hostname, "string"), /cron*/, ""); | ..
```

I got error
`Error in 'eval' command: The expression is malformed. An unexpected character is reached at '/cron*/, "a");'.`

I got confused, what did I do wrong?

Update:
String example:

- `pods-name-cron-3829hr832`
- `pods-name-cron-8923eh32b`

My goal was to remove the `cron-<random_id>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking at the documentation for Splunk Data Stream Processor (DSP), which is not Splunk Enterprise. DSP is an advanced method for bringing data into Splunk Enterprise (amongst other things). You are most likely doing a search which is within Splunk Enterprise, and the docs for that are at https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk

If you are trying to rename a portion of a field and replace it with nothing, you need to use the [replace](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/TextFunctions#replace.28X.2CY.2CZ.29) command

```
... | eval hostname=replace(hostname, "cron*", "") | ..
```

For example, `| makeresults | eval hostname="cronmaster.acme.com" | eval hostname=replace(hostname, "cron", "")` will remove `cron` from `cronmaster.acme.com`

Post an example of the string and what you want it converted to, and we can confirm if the replace is sufficient, or if a regular expression is required.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same command, with a different regular expression. The following looks for `-cron-` followed by any non-whitespace characters, which is represented by `\S+`.

```
| makeresults | eval hostname="pods-name-cron-3829hr832" | eval hostname=replace(hostname, "-cron-\S+", "")
```

Answer (score -1):

Every different version of Splunk might have different functions available for use. Please refer to the documentation according to the Splunk version you are using.

Try this:

```
... | eval hostname=replace(toString(hostname), "/cron*/", "") | ..
```

Here are some links you may find helpful if you are using `Splunk 7.3.1`:

- [Conversion Functions](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/7.3.1/SearchReference/ConversionFunctions)
- [Replace function](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/7.3.1/SearchReference/TextFunctions#replace.28X.2CY.2CZ.29)